# Multiple named components with different state

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, state, vuex, vuetify.js

So I am trying to use multiple instances of a component inside a parent component. I am currently using a Vuetify.js tab-control to display each component. 
For each child component I want to load different dynamic data from a external Rest API.

My preferd way to approach this is to pass a prop down to child's so that they can figure out what data to load. I have a vuex store for each type of child, but would like to reuse template for both, since the data is identical besides values.

**Parent/Wrapper**

```
<template>
<div>
  <v-tabs fixed-tabs>
    <v-tab>
      PackagesType1
    </v-tab>
    <v-tab>
      PackagesType2
    </v-tab>
    <v-tab-item>
      <packages packageType="packageType1"/>
    </v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item>
      <packages packageType="packageType2"/>
    </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Packages from './Packages'

export default {
  components: {
    Packages
  }
}
</script>
```

**Named child component**

```
<template>
<v-container fluid>
<v-data-table v-if="packageType1"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="packageType1"
  >
    <div>
        //ITEM TEMPLATE
    </div
  </v-data-table>
  <v-data-table v-else-if="packagesType2"
    :items="packagesType2"
  >
    <div>
        //ITEM TEMPLATE
    </div
  </v-data-table>
</v-container>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      name: 'packages'
    }
  },
  props: ['packageType'],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('packageModule1', ['packageType1']),
    ...mapGetters('packageModule2', ['packagesType2'])
  },
  methods: {
    getPackageByType () {
      if (this.packageType === 'packageType1') {
        this.getPackageType1()
        return
      }
      this.getPackageType2()
    },
    getPackageType1 () {
      this.$store.dispatch('chocoPackagesModule/getPackageType1')
        .then(_ => {
          this.isLoading = false
        })
    },
    getPackageType2 () {
      this.$store.dispatch('packagesType2Module/getPackageType2')
        .then(_ => {
          this.isLoading = false
        })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getPackageByType()
  }
}
</script>
```

Right now it renders only `packageType1` when loading.

1. How can I easily differ those types without duplicating everything?
2. Should I just hard differ those types? Make separate child-components and role with it that way? I am new to this, but would love as much reuse as possible.

Comment: `v-if="packageType1"` will always return true. Shouldn't it be `v-if="packageType === 'packageType1'"`?

Comment: That may well be. Will check it out